# How to call + (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data this method from another class or method in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know how to call instance method and class method.
I am a little bit confused that how to call below method from another class or method because it returns the string.

```
+ (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data;
```

Comment: It is a class method and you can call using class name directly, no need to create instance of the class

Comment: got it. I was very simple. Simply I wasted my time. Anyways... thank you.

Comment: Possible solution: Do it in a `NSData` Category? Also, it's the same way as you do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@feger", someThing];`, it returns a String in that case, where `NSString` is the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have declared this method in ViewController like this,

```
+ (NSString *)contentTypeForImageData:(NSData *)data{
    //YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    return YOUR_STRING;
}
```

You can call it like this and handle return value as well.

```
NSString *tmpString = [ViewController contentTypeForImageData:YOUR_DATA];
```

For more reference, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassMethod.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's class method and if you want to call this method then you need to call it by class itself, means you do not need to call it by object of the class.

For EX.

If you declared that method in class name **ABC** then you can call it like

```
NSString *strReturnVal = [ABC contentTypeForImageData:yourData];
NSLog("%@", strReturnVal)
```

It will return string so you have to store return value as string.